# Visualforce page not showing as an option in a Quick Action for launching a VF page

Tags: visualforce

I have this VF page I want to launch form a Quick Action in the Cuadre__c object layout but there is no option showing when I want to select the page:

[image]

Sorry it's in spanish, my client has it like this, but the problem is that there is not VF to be selected and it's weird because the page is giving no errors.

```
<apex:page StandardController="Pago__c" extensions="MultiAdd" id="thePage">
<apex:form >
<apex:pageblock id="pb">
    <apex:pageBlockButtons >
        <apex:commandbutton value="Add" action="{!Add}" rerender="pb1"/>
        <apex:commandbutton value="Save" action="{!Save}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockButtons>
    
        
        <apex:pageblock id="pb1">
            
        <apex:repeat value="{!pagoInner}" var="pago" id="therepeat">
                <apex:panelGrid columns="5">
                
                <apex:panelGrid headerClass="Name">
                    <apex:facet name="header">Del</apex:facet>
                    <apex:commandButton value="X" action="{!Del}" rerender="pb1">
                        <apex:param name="rowToBeDeleted" value="{!pago.recCount}" assignTo="{!selectedRowIndex}"></apex:param>
                    </apex:commandButton>
                </apex:panelGrid>   
                
                <apex:panelGrid title="SPD" >
                    <apex:facet name="header">Forma de Pago</apex:facet>
                    <apex:inputfield value="{!pago.pago.FormaPago__c}"/>
                </apex:panelGrid>
                
                <apex:panelGrid >
                    <apex:facet name="header">Tipo de Pago</apex:facet>
                    <apex:inputfield value="{!pago.pago.Tipo__c}"/>
                </apex:panelGrid>
                
                <apex:panelGrid >
                    <apex:facet name="header">Nombre</apex:facet>
                    <apex:inputfield value="{!pago.pago.Name}"/>
                </apex:panelGrid>
            </apex:panelgrid>
        </apex:repeat>
    </apex:pageBlock>
        
</apex:pageblock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

I don't know if this last bit of the page has something to do with it because it's hightlighted in red and I also can't figure out why sience the blocks are properly closed.

[image]

This is the page controller:

```
public class MultiAdd
{
    
    //will hold the pago__c records to be saved
    public List<Pago__c> pagoList  = new List<Pago__c>();
    
    //list of the inner class
    public List<innerClass> pagoInner 
    {   get;set;    }
    
    //will indicate the row to be deleted
    public String selectedRowIndex
    {get;set;}  
    
    //no. of rows added/records in the inner class list
    public Integer count = 1;
    //{get;set;}
    
    
    ////save the records by adding the elements in the inner class list to pagoList,return to the same page
    public PageReference Save()
    {
        PageReference pr = new PageReference('/apex/MultiAdd');
        
        for(Integer j = 0;j< pagoInner.size(); j++)
        {
            pagoList.add(pagoInner[j].pago);
        } 
        insert pagoList;
        pr.setRedirect(True);
        return pr;
    }
        
    //add one more row
    public void Add()
    {   
        count = count+1;
        addMore();      
    }
    
    /*Begin addMore*/
    public void addMore()
    {
        //call to the iner class constructor
        innerClass objInnerClass = new innerClass(count);
        
        //add the record to the inner class list
        pagoInner.add(objInnerClass);    
        system.debug('pagoInner---->'+pagoInner);            
    }/* end addMore*/
    
    /* begin delete */
    public void Del()
    {
        system.debug('selected row index---->'+selectedRowIndex);
        pagoInner.remove(Integer.valueOf(selectedRowIndex)-1);
        count = count - 1;
        
    }/*End del*/
    
    
    
    /*Constructor*/
    public MultiAdd(ApexPages.StandardController ctlr)
    {
    
        pagoInner = new List<innerClass>();
        addMore();
        selectedRowIndex = '0';
        
    }/*End Constructor*/
        


    /*Inner Class*/
    public class innerClass
    {       
        /*recCount acts as a index for a row. This will be helpful to identify the row to be deleted */
        public String recCount
        {get;set;}
        
        
        public Pago__c pago 
        {get;set;}
        
        /*Inner Class Constructor*/
        public innerClass(Integer intCount)
        {
            recCount = String.valueOf(intCount);        
            
            /*create a new Pago*/
            pago = new Pago__c();
            
        }/*End Inner class Constructor*/    
    }/*End inner Class*/
}/*End Class*/
```

Is this a common error ?? What am I doing wrong ??

Thanks a lot for reading and for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Quick Action on object `Cuadre__c` can use only VF pages associated with the standard controller for `Cuadre__c`. Your VF page is for `Pago__c`'s standard controller.

This is because the quickAction on a `Cuadre__c` page passes the `Cuadre__c`'s ID to the standardcontroller which then has access to the underlying record.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the answer !!! I've changed my code so now I have this vf page but with this custom controller called cargarPagosVFController. It works fine when I preview it but I have the same problem when trying to add it to any custom object like Cuadre__c, it just won't show up. If I add the custom controller for Cuadre__c and then extend it, and add this custom controller cargarPagosVFController as the extension, I get an error ;(  Could you help me out ?

Comment: why can't you create a standardcontroller for `Cuadre__c` that collects from the user the data needed to perform whatever you need to do?  Quickactions can only be bound to VF pages for the same standardcontroller as the QuickAction's object. You could even have a trivial VF page on `Cuadre__c` that redirects to the custom controller/page

Comment: Hmmmm ... because I'm new imagining this kind of solutions !! Thanks a LOT for the help !!!